# Replace var placeholder results in an unwanted new line

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I wish to replace `${var}` placeholders in a `nginx.conf` file with env vars loaded from `.env` file (docker). I choose the `${var}` syntax myself in line with docker-compose.

- content `.env` file:

  ```
  DOMAIN_NAME=sub.domain.net
  DB_USER=admin
  ...
  ```

Doing `sed` string replace on this line e.g. is giving me headaches.

- Text input:

  ```
  server_name ${DOMAIN_NAME};
  ```
- command:

  ```
  source .env

  export DOMAIN_NAME

  sed -i "s/\${DOMAIN_NAME}/$DOMAIN_NAME/g" "$docker_root"/nginx/nginx.conf
  ```
- desired outcome:

  ```
  server_name sub.domain.net;
  ```
- but what I get is:

  ```
  server_name sub.domain.net
  ;
  ```

It doesn't even matter what follows the `${var}` replacement. If I add a space and a word behind the placeholder, the word also ends up on the second line.

I used `envsubst` first and saw the same behavior there first. Then I tried with `sed` wich is doing the same :)

I tried a variety of escape slashes, single quotes and double quotes with no result.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Windows style CRLF (carriage return, line feed) line endings in the files as I was working on Windows.

In response to Steeldriver's comment pointing that out,
I converted the files with dos2unix from CRLF to LF (linux & mac).

```
apt install dos2unix
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

The starting point was replacing NGINX placeholders with docker .env file variables. The NGINX built-in mechanism using envsubst wasn't working for me.
[These guys ran in the same issue](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/422#issuecomment-644299743).

For normal use cases, you can follow the instructions [here](https://devopsian.net/notes/docker-nginx-template-env-vars/).